# Using function in c# to return database values index by field names

Tags: c#, function, methods, sqldatareader, reader

I am trying to use a function to return values from a table and I cannot decide what's best way of doing this. Using SqlDataReader, dictionary, string array?
When calling the function I need to reference the data with field name string.

```
    public SqlDataReader staffInfo(string field, string Username)
    {
        string chk_PR = this.Is_PR_Staff(Username) == true ? BW_Config.default_postroom_staff : "";

        string strDBConn = db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strDBConn);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + field + " FROM BW_GetStaffInfo('" + Username + "', '" + chk_PR + "')";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the function:

```
SqlDataReader userInfo = User.staffInfo("StaffCode, GroupIDs, Perms", User.getUsername());

string staffCode = userInfo["StaffCode"].ToString());
```

It works but strange problem it will loop forever sometimes..
I would like a similar method where it's doing the same thing but where it can handle nulls and efficient way of doing this using alternative like dictionary or string array if possible?

thanks

Comment: Use a `using` statement for the `SqlDataReader` also, then return the `SqlDataReader` object. Or you can return a `DataTable` object too if you wish.

Comment: Please use parameterized queries to avoid [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) hacks.  Your method openly invites a potential attacker to pass in something like `'nothing'; <insert hack> --comment out the rest of your original query`.

Answer (score 0):

how bout this? i adapted it from my vb code, i dont know if there are syntax errors, but you should know the gist of it. ;)

```
public Dictionary<String, Object> staffInfo(string field, string Username)
{
    string chk_PR = this.Is_PR_Staff(Username) == true ? BW_Config.default_postroom_staff : "";

    string strDBConn = db.getDBstring(Globals.booDebug);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strDBConn);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + field + " FROM BW_GetStaffInfo('" + Username + "', '" + chk_PR + "')";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Dictionary<String, Object> row = new Dictionary<String, Object>;
            Object obj = nothing;
            for (i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++){
                obj = reader.GetValue(i);
                if (IsDBNull(obj)){
                    obj = "";
                }
                row.add(reader.GetName(i), obj);
            }
            return row;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SqlDataReader, Array, or Dictionary - I'd opt for [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Dapper is a miro ORM. Stackexchange built it and uses it. Simply put, It will allow you to:

> Execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List

Simple example assuming an Employee class / table.

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
    }

    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("SOME CONNECTION STRING")
    { 
        var employees = db.Query<Employee>("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE").ToList(); 
    }
```